# Recursively copy user-executable files

Tags: bash

How can I **recursively** copy all user-executable files in a folder to another folder?

Example, say I have

In folder `folder/one`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group 7777777 Jun  1 12:00 executable1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group    4444 Jun  1 12:00 text1.txt
```

In folder `folder/two`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group 7777777 Jun  1 12:00 executable2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group    4444 Jun  1 12:00 text2.txt
```

it should only recursively copy `executable1` and `executable2` from `folder` to the destination folder without preserving original hierarchy.

Destination folder should have:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group 7777777 Jun  1 12:00 executable2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group 7777777 Jun  1 12:00 executable1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the find command:

```
 find folder -type f -executable -exec echo "{}" /tmp \;
```

Replace `echo` with `cp -p` after you verify that the output is correct.

Comment: The OP will want `cp -p`.

Comment: If dealing with a big tree you should replace `\;` with `+` or use `xargs` instead to save time and only run one `cp` (possibly broken up into multiple if you have a lot of executables)